# How should I encode a pattern made up of alphabets and letters?

Tags: c

a b c d e 6
b c d e 6 5

c d e 6 5 4

d e 6 5 4 3

e 6 5 4 3 2

6 5 4 3 2 1

Based on the input I received from the user, I want to create a similar pattern. Basically I wrote a code but I don't know how to do it.

```
for(i=1; i<=rows; i++){//parent for loop
        for(j=rows; j>=i; j--){
        printf(" ");//print space for pyramid shape
        }
        for(k=1; k<=i; k++){
        printf("%c",ch++);
          }//make right site of pyramid
        ch--;
        for(m=1; m<i; m++){
            printf("%c",--ch);
        }//make left site of pyramid
        printf("\n");
```

Comment: Are you looking to create a hash based on user input or how is the user data related to the output you want?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show what output you expect based on which user input. What do you consider to be "similar pattern"? Based on those samples it could be "hex digits" or "any letter or digit". Or is only the first line input and you just want to shift the characters?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clearly show example input and expected output. From "_for pyramid shape_" in the comments, my **guess** is that you want to _produce_ the first six lines in response to an input of "`6`" (and that, perhaps, an input of "`3`" should produce `a b 3`, `a 3 2` and `3 2 1`), but that's only a guess... you need to clarify things.

Comment: I solved my problem as I showed it, thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    int i,j,ch1=65,n,ch2=66,k,p;
        
        printf("please input a number");
        scanf("%d",&n);
            for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
            
            printf("%c",ch1++);
                for(j=n;j>i;j--){
            
            
                printf("%c",ch2);
                ch2++;
                                }
            
                for(k=n+1;k>n-i+1;k--){
                
                printf("%d",k);
                                      }
            printf("\n");
            ch2=66+i;
                            }
        for(p=n+1;p>=1;p--){
            printf("%d",p);
                           }
    return 0;
}
```